# An error when you override non-virtual-function in C++

Tags: c++, virtual

When you override a member function that is not virtual in a class with no virtual functions, VS compilers occurs the "_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID" error.

For example,

```
class A{
public:
    int a;
public:
    void func(){}
    ~A(){}
};

class B : public A{
public:
    virtual void func(){}

    ~B(){}
};

int main(void){
    A* a = new B();
    delete a;  // error!

    return 0;
}
```

I guess this is because in main(), the a has vtable but the compiler misses it and can't get the exact size of the header?

Somebody can get my curiosity about this shattered?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A does not have a vtable as there are no virtual functions in it. A is a POD class.

Comment: @jmucchiello `A` has a user-defined destructor, so it doesn't qualify as a POD.  Close, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove `A::func()` and the program is still erroneous.

The real reason is that `A::~A()` (not `B::~B()`) is being called on an object of type `B`.

See [C++ FAQ § 20.7](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html#faq-20.7) "When should my destructor be `virtual`?"

Comment: Thanks, but what if I let A::~A() be same, and change void func() to virtual void func()? Then the error is gone, which is why I didn't remove A::func() from class A.

Comment: @YayCplusplus: Purely by accident of memory layout.  It's still undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to destroy an object using pointer to the base class, but the destructor is not virtual. If a class is part of a inheritance hierarchy, *always* make dtors virtual.

Comment: Well, non-virtual destructors are fine if you never call the wrong one.  But that's not the case here.